# Bootstrap 4 Modal Will Not Load In AspNet View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap Modal will not load. It should load as soon as the View is rendered.

I've used this method of adding javascript through a section decleration to load a modal form in the same project. So, I know the jquery and bootstrap libraries that are included in the master pages are compatible. I just cannot figure out why this time around, the modal is not loading.

Browser console is not complaining about anything

My View

```
@using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report Post";
}



<div class="modal fade" id="ReportReasonModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-notify modal-warning" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header text-center" style="background-color:saddlebrown; color:white;">
            <h4 class="modal-title white-text w-100 font-weight-bold py-2">Report Posting</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="/Items/Process Report">
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                @*  @Html.Captcha("Refresh", "Please Enter Captcha Value Below", 7, "Is required field.", false)*@
                <button value="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Submit</button>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts
{
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("ReportReasonModal").modal();
        alert("here")
    });
</script>

}
```

Order of javascript loaded: excerpt from rendered masterpage with the scripts section rendered

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<!-- Popper -->
<script src="/Scripts/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/mdb/mdb.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("ReportReasonModal").modal();
        alert("here")
    });
</script>
```

The modal should appear as soon as the view is rendered

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct jQuery selector. The `#` is missing, to select an element with the id of ReportReasonModal. What you are currently trying to do is select an element of type `<ReportReasonModal />`

```
$("#ReportReasonModal").modal();
```

Comment: Thanks Marco. Using new bifocals, which lead to this ridiculous mistake

Comment: We've all been there.`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`